# @font-face on android native browser not working

Tags: android, css, font-face

Been troubleshooting for hours and can't seem to find anything that'll work fine for my project.
The problem is that font-face is working in all major browsers except for the native browser for android, tested on Samsung S2-S3, Xperia M etc..

Some code...

```
/* Generated by Font Squirrel (http://www.fontsquirrel.com) */

@font-face {
font-family: 'vaud_display_regular_book';
src: url('fonts/vauddisplaybook-webfont.eot');
src: url('fonts/vauddisplaybook-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
    url('fonts/vauddisplaybook-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
    url('fonts/vauddisplaybook-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), 
    url('fonts/vauddisplaybook-webfont.svg#vaud_displayregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

/*... etc got about 22 differents fonts */

@font-face {
font-family: 'virginia_boldregular';
text-transform: uppercase;
src: url('fonts/TypeAssociates-VirginiaBold.eot#') format('eot');
src: url('fonts/TypeAssociates-VirginiaBold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
   url('fonts/TypeAssociates-VirginiaBold.woff') format('woff'), 
   url('fonts/TypeAssociates-VirginiaBold.ttf') format('truetype'), 
   url('fonts/TypeAssociates-VirginiaBold.svg#virginia_boldregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Tested width svg format in media queries and so on...

Can't find any good answers... So pls if you can help... Enlighten me..

Oh, this project is allso built with foundation 3...

Comment: Not enough code. HTML is missing, and so is information about the origin of the font. The problem cannot be reconstructed from the data given. And you should reduce the problem to a simple case, presumably a very simple HTML document that uses *one* font via `@font-face`.

Comment: Ok, thank you will try do recunstruct the issue with smaller amount of code... problem is that this is a really large project where i'm not the only one involved...